# Is the statement "x = map[keyPotentiallyNotYetInMap]" useful for anything?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

Say I have a map

```
map<string, string> m;
```

And do a

```
string x = m["asdf"];
```

without knowing if "asdf" is in the map or not. Then I won't be able to reliably figure out if it was in the map or not by looking at `x`. Is that correct?

So I should have done a `m.first(asdf)` first to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map::operator[]` inserts the key in the map with a default value, if not there.

If you do not want that:

```
std::map<string, string>::iterator it = m.find("asdf");
//if you use C++11:
//auto it = m.find("asdf");
if (it == m.end())
    std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "The value is " << *it << std::endl;
```

The `map::operator[]` is useful for many things, particularly with references. For example:

```
std::string &x = m["asdf"];
x += "X";
```

That will add an `"X"` to the (possibly newly created) string in the map.

Answer (score 2):

> Then I won't be able to reliably figure out if it was in the map or not by looking at x. Is that correct?

You are right. It'll be default constructed in case it's missing.

You should use [`m.count("asdf")`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/count/) (just find out if it exists) or [`m.find("asdf")`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/) (plus, get the reference if it exists) to find out whether it exists. Depending on your requirements.

Comment: Would "default constructed" result in an empty string? In my case I get some random value and sometimes access violations, depending on what I do with the returned value. This is Microsoft C++.

Comment: +1 Although I eventually decided to accept rodrigo's answer for the examples, even though you answer more directly to my question. Both answers were equally helpful for me, but rodrigo's has examples for those who don't know how to use `find`, which I always find helpful. Otoh, you have the mentioning of `count` in there...

Comment: I know, that's the site I'm coming from. It does not talk about string's default constructor though. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/ says `string() Content is initialized to an empty string.` which does not seem to happen in my case...

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy then there probably is another issue with your code or build process.

Answer (score 1):

x will be the default constructed std::string. std::map requires a default constructor when operator[] is compiled.

Comment: I think you meant default constructor.  And `std::map` doesn't require a default constructor, unless you use `std::map::operator[]`.

Answer (score 0):

First, operator[] will construct the 'value' object, if one is missing *using value initialization* rather than default constructor. This means using the default constructor where appropriate and initializing with zeros for built-in types cases (ints, floats, pointers), and a recursive value initialization for aggregates (like simple structs).

You are right that if you obtain a value-constructed object from operator[], you will not know if it was there in the map or if it was generated on the fly. Another problem with operator[] is that it is not a const member.

Nonetheless, the operator is sometimes useful. For instance, if I use a map to store a word count of some text,

```
unsigned countCats( std::map<std::string, unsigned> dict )
{
  unsigned count = disc["cat"];
}
```

The operator works exactly as you would expect.